# How to evaluate $(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})\cdot (\mathbf{a} - \mathbf{b})$

Tags: vectors

The answer is $\mathbf 0$ but I don't understand how to get to this answer.

If the answer is $\mathbf 0$ then that means $(\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{b})$ is perpendicular to $(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})$, can someone please explain to me why $(\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{b})$ is perpendicular to $(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})$

Comment: What is $axb$? Is that a cross product?

Comment: I'm assuming $x$ is cross product?

Comment: $a\times b$ ir orthogonal to $a$ and $b.$ And thus ...

Comment: Yes it's the cross product, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I don't think this really warrants an answer, but since $(a\times b)\cdot a = (a\times b)\cdot b = 0$, $$(a\times b)\cdot (a-b) = (a\times b)\cdot a - (a\times b)\cdot b = 0$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact there is an easy reason why this must be true: $a-b$ lies in the plane of $a,b$, while $a \times b$ is perpendicular to that whole plane.

Comment: Can you please explain why $a-b$ lies on the same plane as $a$ and $b$? If, say, $c$ is introduced, then does that mean $a-b-c$ lies on the same plane as $a$, $b$ and $c$?

Comment: @Spica any linear combination of two ($n$) vectores lies in the ($n$-) plane defined by those vectors. That is precisely a definition of a plane. If your vector $c$ doesn't lie on the same plane, then $a-b-c$ will not lie on such a plane.

Comment: @Spica Exactly what Dog_69 wrote. $2$ vectors define a plane, so adding and subtracting $2$ vectors will stay in the same plane. $a,b,c$ do not necessarily lie in the same plane (because they are $3$ vectors, not $2$ -- consider the case where one is along each of the three coordinate axes), but if they do, then adding and subtracting them will keep you in that same plane.

Comment: @Spica Thinking about this geometrically may help. Alternatively, suppose (WLOG) that $a,b$ are in the $xy$-plane, i.e., the plane with $z$-coordinate $0$. Let $a=(a_1,a_2,0)$ and $b=(b_1,b_2,0)$. Then $a-b=(a_1-b_1,a_2-b_2,0)$ which is still in the $xy$-plane.

Answer (score 1):

When two vectors are added they lie on the same plane which the original two vectors are placed.(Therefore (a-b),(a+b),(2a+b).... all lie on the same plane  which a and b are on.)

Further, the cross product of two vectors is perpendicular  to both the original vectors.(a cross b results a vector and that vector is perpendicular to both a and b.)

Then we know that dot product of two parallel vectors is zero.(Dot product results a scalar.)

By the above facts we can derive your answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$(a\times b).(a-b)$$is a determinant with rows being $a,b,a-b$

That determinant is zero because the rows are linearly dependent.